# android gradle //noinspection GradleCompatible

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

What does it mean in android gradle.

adding **//noinspection GradleCompatible** has resolve the conflict issue with dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

- You can get this warning for your gradle configuration for example if
  your app code is mixing library versions.
- A common example of this happening is with the Android support
  libraries.
- Also if additional 3rd party libraries included in your project are
  using different versions, that can also present warnings.
- Android Studio will show you details of the error message, before you suppress it with 'GradleCompatible' by hovering over the red warning line in the IDE (see attached screenshot).
- '//noinspection GradleCompatible' just suppresses the warning.
  Basically do not inspect issues with Gradle compatibility, as relates
  to the next line of the config.

[image: Example of GradleCompatible warning in Android Studio IDE]

Comment: Ok i got the reason for happening but I want to know that what actually  is the role of this line //noinspection GradleCompatible.

Comment: //noinspection GradleCompatible - just suppresses the warning. Basically do not inspect issues with Gradle compatibility, as relates to the next line of the config. (added to my answer).

Comment: Is it safe to use it? Or does it expose us to run time crashed a lot

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and finally I have added this line by pressing `alt+enter`, but before that check if the app compat library version is latest version that there is available for your app's target sdk version.

If that is okay and you are still getting the problem then do this by pressing `alt+enter` key (in *ubuntu* and *windows*) and (in mac os (os x) use command +shift +enter)  add `noinspection GradleCompatible` this will help!

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see the comment //noinspection GradleCompatible, it usually means that the developer is intentionally ignoring a lint warning related to Gradle compatibility. This comment tells the lint tool to ignore that specific warning for the annotated code block or element.

It's important to note that while suppressing lint warnings can be a temporary solution, it's generally recommended to address the root cause of the issue to ensure the stability and compatibility of your Android project in the long run. If you encounter such comments in your codebase, it might be a good idea to review the Gradle files and dependencies to ensure that everything is set up correctly.